# Can I enable assertions for debug builds in Android using Gradle?

Tags: android, gradle, adb

Is there a good way to enable assertions automatically for debug builds using Gradle (usually done with `adb shell setprop debug.assert 1`)? Would it be recommended to add a build task which executes a shell command and execute it with assembleDebug?

Is there any way around the conflict that would arise with multiple devices connected? It's not uncommon for me to be developing with a Genymotion emulator and actual device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a general DebugUtility class which will throw a custom exception (if in debug mode).  I've stopped using asserts. Android Studio actually warns when you use assertions, saying to use the BuildConfig.DEBUG conditional checks instead.